# what's the difference between /etc/locale.conf and /etc/environment?

Tags: centos, locale

What's the difference between the following files in CentOS 7?

- `/etc/locale.conf`
- `/etc/environment`
- `~/.bashrc`

Comment: any `bashrc` file is for bash shell. The other two files are shell-independent. An app started at boot could check `environment` and `locale.conf` to see what environment variables are set, which locale is used by the system, in which locale to write logs, etc

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but why two file? why not use environment only? why not just use locale.conf only? what's the exactly difference between this two file?

Comment: /etc/locale.conf is used to set language and coutry settings, such as the currency symbol ..... /etc/environment sets systemwide settings, such as the PATH variable, default editor, etc

Answer (score 6):

For any program that simply needs to *read* the environment variable settings, `/etc/locale.conf` and `/etc/environment` are basically the same; in a very simplified embedded system, you could omit `/etc/locale.conf` and place any required locale variables to `/etc/environment` instead.

The difference is mainly in how to deal with *updating* the files.

For `/etc/locale.conf`, the set of variables expected to be defined in the file is finite and their syntax is well-defined. This allows easier modification by programs. For example, a "language/locale settings" GUI application can easily read the existing settings, present them to the user, and then *re-write the entire file* if the user makes new choices.

Recovery from syntax errors is simple too: if the settings application detects a syntax error in the file, it can just present the settings it managed to read, let the user either accept the current configuration or make changes, and then re-write the file based on some template built into the application, and the error is transparently fixed.

For `/etc/environment`, the set of environment variables that can be defined there is unlimited, so any programmatic manipulations of the file must be done much more carefully.

Also, `/etc/environment` and `/etc/locale.conf` define *system-wide* defaults, while `~/.bashrc` is *specific* to the user: using `~/.bashrc`, the user can override the system defaults for their own session(s) only, if desired.

Comment: Thank you, I found that `/etc/locale.conf` only appear in CentOS7, and this file can be set by one of `systemd` component - `localectl` while `/etc/environment` should be edit by yourself. In CentOS6 or earlier version, there is a `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`, but this file was removed in CentOS7, so is that `/etc/locale.conf` is the replacement of `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` ?

Comment: Yes. `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` (and in fact the entire `/etc/sysconfig` directory) was a classic RedHat-style solution, while `/etc/locale.conf` might become the new standard across most Linux distributions. Likewise, RedHat/CentOS/Fedora and related distributions used to include tools (both command line and GUI) to manipulate `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`, while `/etc/environment` was left to the system administrator to edit manually.